# Multiple hibernate user transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I am trying multiple transactions in the same method in java on a web application with jboss and hibernate.

So I know that basically you do: begintransaction -> commit / rollback -> close

What I would like to do is to commit/rollback in a for loop. For a list of objects I am making updates and if everything went right I commit each object separately or I rollback.

The problem is that I have already the same kind of errors: either the session is closed or invalid or the transaction is invalid or the objects are detached (if I clear the entitymanager).

I tried a looooooooooooooooot of different things I found on the internet but none worked. The last thing I tried was to use the entitymanager:
em.flush (if the updates went right => this works), but if there is a problem I tried to rollback (this is detaching the objects and the next flush doesn't work anymore in the for loop).

So my question is: what is the right way to commit / rollback each object like this:

```
for (Object obj : objects) {
//Operations
 if(ok) {
  commit
 }
else {
  rollback
 }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I forgot to point out that I work with seam 3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, in the `for` loop, calling a `@Transactional` method with each object as the argument? exception handling included ofc

Comment: Yes I tried, I got an error. Sadly I do not remember which one exactly because I tried so many things but I tried to put the whole operation lines in a different method called with @Transactional annotated. Didn't work :s

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to go back to @Transactional and I found @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEw_REQUIRED) which should create a new transaction each time I enter my method, but it doesn't. What is really happening is that the flush isn't working at the end of my method and it seems like the flush is made at the end of all the for loop. I tried to force the flushmode to manual but it didn't work because it is still flushing at the end of everything and not for each object. As soon as I try to use rollback, the session is deleted and I get:org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Actually after all my research, all I found is that I have to use rollback. Didnt find any solution without using it. So the real question is: how do I create a new session after rollback "destroyed" the first one ?